# how to keep value of first set of values and remove all other from the list

Tags: c#

I have duplicate `Name` is coming for different `Standard` like below,

```
 var lstData = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {Name = "A", Standard = "sd1"},
            new Data {Name = "B", Standard = "sd1"},
            new Data {Name = "C", Standard = "sd1"},

            new Data {Name = "A", Standard = "sd2"},
            new Data {Name = "B", Standard = "sd2"},
            new Data {Name = "C", Standard = "sd2"},
        };
```

Now I want to keep only first set (`std1` data) and subsequent set (`std2`) I want to remove from list.

How to do this?

```
            new Data {Name = "A", Standard = "sd1"},
            new Data {Name = "B", Standard = "sd1"},
            new Data {Name = "C", Standard = "sd1"},
```

Here all values of `Name` and `standard` are dynamic (value is different for every run of my program), here I am giving value A, B, C, std1, std2 are just sample values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all the items by the `Name` property, and then take the `First` item from each group:

```
List<Data> results = lstData
    .GroupBy(data => data.Name)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` has a [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) method, which accepts a [predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1) that defines which elements to remove. So grab the first value, then remove anything that doesn't match:

```
var firstStandard = lstData[0].Standard;
lstData.RemoveAll(d => d.Standard != firstStandard);
```

This will probably perform slightly quicker than the answer Rufus gave (depending on the size of the list) since you aren't traversing the entire list more than once.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't hard code std2. These are just sample values. My values are NOT fixed

Comment: @user584018 I think I understand. I updated my answer.